# An ascending union of reduced FATR groups is FATR

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

My question is taken out of a proof in the book "Infinite Soluble Groups" by Robinson and Lennox.

Let me paste the proof first:

[image]

Some reminders:

a soluble group $G$ has FATR (finite abelian total rank) if it has a series $G \triangleright G_1 \triangleright...\triangleright G_n=1$ in which every quotient factor is abelian of finite total rank.

A constructible soluble group here can be understood as being built up of finite extensions of soluble groups and ascending HNN extensions as is displayed in the above proof, where the base $S$ is already constructible.

My question is how exactly are they concluding, in the above proof, that $S^G$ (normal closure of $S$ in $G$) has FATR (or is minimax by induction even), based on the fact that $S$ does.

We prove earlier in the book that in this case of an ascending HNN extension that:

$S \leq tSt^{-1} \leq ... \leq t^{i}St^{-i}\leq...$

and that $S^G = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}t^{i}St^{-i}$ and so $G = \langle t, S|t^{-1}st=\sigma(s), s\in S\rangle=S^G\rtimes\langle t \rangle$.

Most attempts I had failed because of the fact that $S$ may not be normal in $G$, so I couldn't find a meaningful way to build a normal series for $S^G$ with quotients abelian of finite total rank.

Some notes:

Notice that the induction gives that $S$ is reduced and minimax, not just FATR.

The attempts discussed in the comments, from what I understand, do not work in general.

Comment: I don't exactly what total rank means, but I would guess that if $S \rhd S_1 \rhd \cdots \rhd S_n=1$ is a series for $S$ with abelian quotiens of finite total rank, then the same applies to the series $S^G \rhd S_1^G \rhd \cdots \rhd S_n^G =1$ of $G$, where each  $S_k^G = \cup_{i=1}^\infty t^iS_kt_i^{-1}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt the total rank is the torsion-free rank plus the sum of all $p$-ranks. (So you are allowed Pruefer groups in there.)

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks, this was my first guess as well, but, and please correct me if I'm wrong, this series doesn't consist of subgroups even, because we can't guarantee that $\sigma(x) \in S_k$ when $x \in S_k$ (maybe I'm missing something though).

Comment: Can you not choose the $S_i$ to be fully invariant, and hence $\sigma(x)\in S_k$? Obviously the derived series is fully invariant, and since FATR is closed under subquotients you should be able to use the derived series. But it's been a while since I did any of this stuff.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven yes I can assume $S_i$ to be fully-invariant (in $S$) but $S$ isn't normal in $G$ so I can't guarantee that $S_i$ is normal in $G$. Is there a way to choose $S_i$ to be fully-invariant in $G$?

Comment: Inside the first stage, $tSt^{-1}$, can we not construct the group $tS_it^{-1}$?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven yes $tS_it^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $tSt^{-1}$

Comment: It also looks normal to me. Can this not be iterated then, to obtain $t^jS_it^{-j}$ inside $t^jSt^{-j}$?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven yes, but we don't have (I think) is $S_i \leq tS_it^{-1} \leq t^2St^{-2} \leq...$ so this union isn't ascending so in general Derek's $S_i^G$ isn't a subgroup as far as I can see.

Comment: I actually thought it was entirely obvious, but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven anyways, we can't really choose $S_i$ to be fully-invariant in $G$, even $S$ isn't because $tSt^{-1}$ isn't contained in $S$ which demonstrates that the derived series can't really be $G$ invariant.

Comment: No, sure. I was relatively convinced that if the $S_i$ were the derived series for $S$, then $S_i\leq tS_it^{-1}$, and I think this is all you need by induction. But I couldn't completely convince myself.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven if $A$ is abelian of finite total rank and $B \leq A$ does $A/B$ have finite total rank (if so I think I can prove this using your earlier comments, but I think $A/B$ doesn't necessarily have finite total rank..)?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven and without this how do we conclude that we can assume the derived series has quotients with finite abelian rank?

Comment: I believe this is true, but as I said, it's been a long time since I looked at this stuff, more than ten years. Finite total rank for an abelian group means it is a sum of a finitely generated abelian group and a finite bunch of Pruefer groups, no? In which case it is closed under quotients.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven ok, do you happen to have a reference for this please?

Comment: 5.1.3 of the book, p.84.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I think the claim that if an abelian $A$ has finite total rank and $B \leq A$ implies that $A/B$ has finite total rank is wrong: take $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $B = \mathbb{Z}$, then $\mathbb{Q}$ is of finite total rank and the quotient $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ has torsion elements of order $p$ for every prime, so its total rank is infinite.

Comment: You are right. I misread it. It says a torsion-free subgroup of finite rank in 5.1.3, which includes subgroups like $\mathbb{Q}$. I thought it meant a free abelian subgroup of finite rank.

Comment: 5.3.7 of L-R states that $S/A$ does indeed have FATR if $A$ is a maximal abelian normal subgroup.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I posted a proposed solution if you're interested. Thank you very much for the helpful discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposed solution:

We have by the induction assumption that $S$ is not only FATR but minimax too. $S$ is solvable as well.

Suppose that $1 = S_m \triangleleft S_{m-1} \triangleleft ... \triangleleft S_1 \triangleleft S_0 = S$ witnesses that $S$ is minimax. That is, each quotient $S_i / S_{i+1}$ has either min or max for $1 \leq i \leq m-1$.

We denote the derived series as $1 = S^{(d)} \triangleleft S^{(d-1)} \triangleleft ... \triangleleft S^{(1)} \triangleleft S^{(0)} = S$.

By Schreier's refinement theorem there are equivalent refinements of the above normal series.

Notice that if $S_i/S_{i+1}$ has max it is clear that in any refinement $S_{i+1} \triangleleft X_1 \triangleleft...\triangleleft X_k \triangleleft S_i$ the quotients have max as well since an ascending sequence of subgroups must stabilize modulo $S_{i+1}$.

In addition, if $S_i/S_{i+1}$ has min we see that each quotient must have min as well.

We got that there is a series of the form

$1 \triangleleft X_1 \triangleleft ... \triangleleft X_r \triangleleft S^{(d-1)} \triangleleft Y_1 \triangleleft ... \triangleleft Y_l \triangleleft S^{(d-2)}...$

where each quotient is abelian and with min or with max.

It follows that each $S^{(i)}/S^{(i+1)}$ is an abelian minimax group.

Denote the total rank of a group by $r(G) = r_0(G) + \sum_{p \text{ prime}}r_p(G)$ where $r_0(G)$ is the torsion free rank, and $r_p(G)$ is the p-rank. For abelian groups it is true that $r(A) \leq r(B) + r(A/B)$.

Hence, $S^{(i)}/S^{(i+1)}$ is of finite total rank because:

1. an abelian group with min is of finite total rank (being a direct sum of finite cyclic groups and quasicyclic groups)
2. an abelian group with max is of finite total rank (being finitely generated)

Now we're in a position to claim that $S^G$ is FATR.

Define $R_{i,j} = t^{i}S^{(j)}t^{-i}$ with the appropriate indexes - it holds that $R_{i,j} \leq R_{i+1,j}$ because $\sigma(S^{(j)}) = t^{-1}S^{(j)}t \subset S^{(j)}$.

Hence, $\cup_{i \geq 1} R_{i,j} := S^{(j)}_G$ is a subgroup.

It is left to show that $1 \triangleleft S^{(d-1)}_G \triangleleft ... \triangleleft S^{(1)}_G \triangleleft S^G$ and that each quotient $S^{(j)}_G/S^{(j+1)}_G \cong S^{(j)}/S^{(j+1)}$.